# Because chatview >=1.0.0 depends on intl ^0.18.0 and mobile_app depends on intl ^0.17.0, chatview >=1.0.0 is forbidden

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have this project which works fine when I had not added [chatview: ^1.2.0+1](https://pub.dev/packages/chatview). Now after adding it as a dependency, I get an error of

```
Because chatview >=1.0.0 depends on intl ^0.18.0 and mobile_app depends on intl ^0.17.0, chatview >=1.0.0 is forbidden.
So, because mobile_app depends on chatview ^1.2.0+1, version solving failed.
pub get failed
command: "/Users/samuel/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "/Users/samuel/flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "vscode.dart-code:flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "/Users/samuel/.pub-cache",
}
exit code: 1
```

Now i changed the version of my `intl` package to `intl ^0.18.0` which I expected to work fine but I also got another error of

```
Because mobile_app depends on flutter_localizations from sdk which depends on intl 0.17.0, intl 0.17.0 is required.
So, because mobile_app depends on intl ^0.18.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed
command: "/Users/samuel/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "/Users/samuel/flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "vscode.dart-code:flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "/Users/samuel/.pub-cache",
}
exit code: 1
```

Now I don't know what to do again. Below is my pubspec.yaml file

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.4 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  get: ^4.6.5
  flutter_svg_provider: ^1.0.3
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.10
  http: ^0.13.5
  image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.18.0
  logger: ^1.1.0
  pretty_http_logger: ^0.2.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.2.0
  package_info_plus: ^3.0.0
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.5.4
  another_flushbar: ^1.12.29
  flutter_fadein:
  avatar_glow: ^2.0.2
  dropdown_search: ^5.0.5
  expandable_text: ^2.3.0
  infinite_scroll_pagination: ^3.2.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  chatview: ^1.2.0+1
```

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.1, on macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-x64, locale en-GH)
Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.75.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So there was a recent update to widen the dependency version of the localisation of flutter sdk to >=0.17.0 <0.19.0

So I just overided my dependency to use 0.18.0 by:

```
dependency_overrides:
  intl: ^0.18.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `flutter_localizations` currently depends on `intl 0.17.0`. So the only option you have, at this time, is to downgrade `chatview` to a version that uses `intl 0.17.0`.

It looks like `flutter_localizations` is being updated to use `intl 0.18.0` but this hasn't hit the stable flutter channel yet.
See: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/117163

Comment: Isn't there any other way? because there are some crucial things I will miss if I downgrade the ```chatview``` package

Answer (score 0):

Overrides dependency in pubspec.yaml file by following

```
dependency_overrides:
  intl: ^0.18.0
```